# when text is entered that is longer than the field, the text is hidden

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, when text is entered that is longer than the field, the text is hidden, as shown in the gif:

[image]

The code from first text form field:

```
Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        labelFormStyle("Nome do equipamento"),
                        Container(
                          height: hasErrorForm && equipmentNameController.text.isEmpty ? 55 : 35,
                          child: Container(
                          height: hasErrorForm && equipmentNameController.text.isEmpty ? 55 : 35,
                          child: TextFormField(
                            validator: (value){
                              return validatorEmpty(value);
                            },
                            controller: equipmentNameController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                            maxLines: null,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14
                            ),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                isDense: true,
                                enabledBorder: enableBorderField(),
                                focusedBorder: enableBorderField(),
                                disabledBorder: enableBorderField(),
                                border: enableBorderField(),
                                focusedErrorBorder: errorBorderField(equipmentNameController.text.isEmpty),
                                errorBorder: errorBorderField(equipmentNameController.text.isEmpty)
                            ),
                            onChanged: (value){
                              if(hasErrorForm){
                                setState(() {
                                  _formKey.currentState!.validate();
                                });
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

How to solve this?

Comment: What platform are you running this code on (Android/iOS/Web/Windows/Linux)?

Comment: Im running in Android 10

Comment: Have you checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900387/multi-line-textfield-in-flutter

Comment: I tried put 
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
)

but the error continues

Comment: Edit your post to show the new code

Comment: The height that you have put on the container may be the problem. I can't test it at the moment. Try commenting out the container size constraints and see what happens. The multiple lines are probably there but you can't see them.

Comment: this worked, but it was too big, I'm sure the designer will disapprove. I wanted to know a way to make it a single line and have scrolling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249968/discussion-between-grahamd-and-gabi-mangili).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by removing the height restriction and putting maxLines: 1. The only problem is that it didn't get the size the designer wanted, but I'll talk to him about it